# VFRemote.js non-uglified/minified

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Has anyone got (or know how to get hold of) a copy of the VFRmote.js in a non-uglified/minified state?

I have, several times, had to debug the JavaScript remoting and run into issues since this is just like a black-box. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ran it through:

http://jsbeautifier.org

This was asked and posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634890/how-to-deminify-javascript) for other js minified libraries. Amazing what google gets ya.

Also, using Developer tools in Safari, to view the page resources gets the pretty version so you can directly copy and paste.

I cannot post the beautified code as it is to long to fit into the message....

Comment: I hadn't even contemplated that *hangs head in shame*. The output will be a great help I'm sure... thanks.

Comment: @ToddHalfpenny - lol, no worries, we all do it. I even called tech support once and told them to skip the basic read of the "check to see if it is plugged in" until I actually looked and the kids had unplugged it......

Comment: Can you put the results in pastebin?